# How would I attach media/images to a post based on a ID stored in a each post's custom field

Tags: posts, custom-field, images, media

I have converted a site over to wordpress recently.  I was able to import all the posts via a CSV importer, but not the images associated with each post.  The post type is "**machinery**".  The custom field with the post's previous ID on the old system of each post is called "**machinery_legacy_idLocation**".  I have an additional table called "**legacy_images**".

"**legacy_images**" has 2 columns "**ListingID**" and "**imageurl**".

"**ListingID**" in the "**legacy_images**" table matches a post with the same   "**machinery_legacy_idLocation**".

Now the "imageurl" matches the title of a corresponding image that I have already added to the media library in Wordpress.

Basically I just need to figure out a way to reattach all these images to all these posts after the move.

Comment: This question is really "too localized" as you asking for a custom importer fitting your special needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_insert_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) will insert an attachment post for a given parent post ID and filename. You can write a little script to query for all your posts with the legacy key, get their associated image paths, and call `wp_insert_attachment` for each.